# Create dynamic object with dynamic keys and non dynamic

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to create nested objects with some dynamic and not dynamic fields

this is my dataset let method = {

```
"97": {
    "mini_id": 75,
    "score": "2",
    "fe_id": 97
  },
  "98": {
    "mini_id": 75,
    "score": "2",
    "fe_id": 98
  },
  "169": {
    "mini_id": 76,
    "score": "1",
    "fe_id": 169
  },
  "170": {
    "mini_id": 76,
    "score": "1",
    "fe_id": 170
  },
  "171": {
    "mini_id": 76,
    "score": "1",
    "fe_id": 171
  },
  "172": {
    "mini_id": 76,
    "score": "3",
    "fe_id": 172
  }
}
```

And I am trying to have the data in the format of

```
var reduced = Object.values(arr).reduce((c,v) => { 
        c[v.mini_id] = c[v.mini_id] || {};
    c[v.mini_id]["fees"][v.fe_id] = c[v.mini_id]["fees"][v.fe_id] || {};
    return c;
}, {})
```

I want my dictionary to look like :

{75: {fees: {97: {....}}}}

Looks like it doesn't like dynamic keys to be mixed with non dynamic. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the parameter "fees" in the sample object you provided? You have used this parameter in the reduce function though.

Comment: there is no fees parameter in the object, I want to hard code it so it looked like 76: {fees: {172:{....}}}

Comment: Can you please consider this adding to your question, about what you expect your object to look like?

Comment: I edited the question, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: There isn't any issue if some of your object was created using dynamic keys and few were static only. What I'm trying to figure out is the end result that you are expecting so that I can further look into this. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet might help you,

```js
const arr = {
  97: {
    mini_id: 75,
    score: "2",
    fe_id: 97,
  },
  98: {
    mini_id: 75,
    score: "2",
    fe_id: 98,
  },
  169: {
    mini_id: 76,
    score: "1",
    fe_id: 169,
  },
  170: {
    mini_id: 76,
    score: "1",
    fe_id: 170,
  },
  171: {
    mini_id: 76,
    score: "1",
    fe_id: 171,
  },
  172: {
    mini_id: 76,
    score: "3",
    fe_id: 172,
  },
};

const reduced = Object.values(arr).reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.mini_id] = c[v.mini_id] ?? { fees: {} };
  c[v.mini_id].fees[v.fe_id] = c[v.mini_id].fees[v.fe_id] ?? {};
  return c;
}, {})

console.log(reduced);
```